# My Dell H825CDW Network printer doesn't print from wired network

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, printing, printer

I have a home network with a verizon router. I am using windows-10. My printer is at 192.168.1.30. I can ping the printer and I can connect to its embedded web server, and it is online. I checked the settings and the port is set correctly. When I try to print a document from my computer, it spools and then disappears. when I check the queue, the document isn't there. And, of course, it doesn't print.

When I try to print from my laptop (using wireless network) it works ok.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is usually to add the printer as a local printer. This also works with Epsons, Cannons, & Ricohs, 
Although with those printers its usually slow to print symptoms, because it was installed with its network name instead of IP address.

1. Load up your printer browser in the control panel,
2. I recommend deleting your network printer and restarting your PC,     it     seems that windows holds on to some information until you restart.
3. Click “Add a Printer”.
4. Now select add local printer.
5. Create new port.
6. When it asks for "Enter a port name" use the following format “\\192.168.1.30\yourprinter”, essentially it’s address and whatever its host-name is on the network.
7. Make sure your printer is setup with a static IP, if it changes with DHCP you would have to repeat these steps

Comment: OK, I did all of the above, but it is still not printing from this computer.

Comment: When you go to the network, what name does the printer show up as?

Comment: Under ports, it says WSD-5650cb60-2add-4b72-beaa-b1baaecd1ea8.0035

Comment: Are you trying to use tcp? Or WSD? (web services for devices).